# Play Framework long "pause" during compilation

Tags: java, playframework, compilation, sbt, typesafe-activator

We have a pretty big Play Framework Application using version 2.5.13.

The compilation time are getting pretty long (small changes to a couple of line may trigger 4-5 minutes compilation).

So I decided to investigate by activating sbt debuging during the compilation.

To do it, after typing "activator", I type "set logLevel := Level.Debug"

I'm able to look at very interesting logs but the problem is that when it "pause" (it's not really pausing because the CPU is high), there is no log and the latest one is this:

```
[debug] [naha] All newly invalidated sources after taking into account (previously) recompiled sources:Set()
```

My question: **Is there any log that I could activate to see what is going on during that very very long step?** At least if I'm able to know what is going on, I could optimize my code to prevent the problem.

Thanks

Comment: what play version do you use ?

Comment: @AndriyKuba Updated the question. It's the latest 2.5.13!

Comment: You can use `scalac` verbose mode. Add the following to your `build.sbt` file: `scalacOptions += "-verbose"`.

Comment: thanks @marcospereira. It effectively show more logs but there is still this moment where it stay stuck for 182 seconds without showing a single log...

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Was there ever a resolution?

Comment: @TimScarborough, please check my blog here: https://medium.com/@jfcote/the-ultimate-solution-to-play-framework-slow-compilation-53f4fd499df4